# Pruebas de Rollback multiple query no previene los primeros

Tags: php, mysql, script

Estoy trabajando sobre un sistema que no tiene una estructura o un patron de diseño ...
y estoy haciendo prebas sobre el como implementar Rollback.
La plataforma es Xampp en su ultima version sobre windows 10

la base de datos tiene la siguiente estructura (DUMP):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `DB_DEMO` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `DB_DEMO`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Tbl_Entradas`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tbl_Entradas` (
  `PK_Entrada` int(13) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID tabla',
  `Doc_Rel` char(28) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID Documento relacionado',
  `Id_Producto` int(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID del producto',
  `Id_Lote` char(28) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID Lote/ Cod de Barra',
  `Cant_Uni` int(13) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unidad de producto',
  `Cant_Peso_Kilo` float(13,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Peso en Bodega',
  `Fecha_Mov` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Fecha de movimiento',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_Entrada`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PK_Entrada` (`PK_Entrada`),
  KEY `xPK_Entrada` (`PK_Entrada`),
  KEY `xDoc_Rel` (`Doc_Rel`),
  KEY `xId_Producto` (`Id_Producto`),
  KEY `xId_Lote` (`Id_Lote`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Tbl_Lote`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tbl_Lote` (
  `PK_Lote` int(13) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID tabla',
  `Id_Producto` int(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID del producto',
  `Id_Lote` char(28) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID Lote/ Cod de Barra',
  `Cant_Uni` int(13) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unidad de producto',
  `Cant_Peso_Kilo` float(13,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Peso en Bodega',
  `Cost_Prom_Lot` float(13,5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Costo Promedio del  Lote',
  `Val_Inv_Lot` float(13,5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Val del Inventario',
  `Localizacion` char(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Localizacion en Bodega',
  `Fecha_Exp` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Fecha de Expiracion',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_Lote`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PK_Lote` (`PK_Lote`),
  KEY `xPK_Lote` (`PK_Lote`),
  KEY `xId_Producto` (`Id_Producto`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Tbl_Saldo`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tbl_Saldo` (
  `PK_Saldo` int(13) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID tabla',
  `Id_Producto` int(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID del producto',
  `Cant_Uni` int(13) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unidad de producto',
  `Cant_Peso_Kilo` float(13,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Peso en Bodega',
  `Cost_Prom` float(13,5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Costo Promedio del  Lote',
  `Val_Inv` float(13,5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Val del Inventario',
  `Ultimo_Corte` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Fecha de ultimo corte de inventario teorico',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_Saldo`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PK_Saldo` (`PK_Saldo`),
  KEY `xPK_Saldo` (`PK_Saldo`),
  KEY `xId_Producto` (`Id_Producto`),
  KEY `xUltimo_Corte` (`Ultimo_Corte`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `Tbl_Saldo` (`PK_Saldo`, `Id_Producto`, `Cant_Uni`, `Cant_Peso_Kilo`, `Cost_Prom`, `Val_Inv`, `Ultimo_Corte`) VALUES
(1, 00277, 0, 0.00, 0.00000, 0.00000, '2019-12-16 00:00:00');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Tbl_Salidas`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tbl_Salidas` (
  `PK_Salidas` int(13) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID tabla',
  `Doc_Rel` char(28) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID Documento relacionado',
  `Id_Producto` int(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID del producto',
  `Id_Lote` char(28) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID Lote/ Cod de Barra',
  `Cant_Uni` int(13) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unidad de producto',
  `Cant_Peso_Kilo` float(13,2) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL COMMENT 'Peso en Bodega',
  `Fecha_Mov` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Fecha de movimiento',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_Salidas`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PK_Salidas` (`PK_Salidas`),
  KEY `xPK_Salidas` (`PK_Salidas`),
  KEY `xDoc_Rel` (`Doc_Rel`),
  KEY `xId_Producto` (`Id_Producto`),
  KEY `xId_Lote` (`Id_Lote`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
COMMIT;
```

El script utilizado para las pruebas es el siguiente:

```
public function Test_SetData(){
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=DB_DEMO", DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $conn->beginTransaction();
        $conn->exec("set names utf8");
        $conn->exec('USE DB_DEMO');
        $conn->exec("INSERT INTO Tbl_Entradas(Doc_Rel, Id_Producto, Id_Lote, Cant_Uni, Cant_Peso_Kilo, Fecha_Mov) VALUES ('RIMP000001','00277','0000000000001',(2480*4),24800,'2019-12-16 09:15:00');");
        $conn->exec("INSERT INTO Tbl_Lote(Id_Producto, Id_Lote, Cant_Uni, Cant_Peso_Kilo, Cost_Prom_Lot, Val_Inv_Lot, Localizacion, Fecha_Exp) VALUES ('00277','0000000000001',(2480*4),24800,1.00,1.00,'AAA1','2020-01-29');");
        $conn->exec("UPDATE Tbl_Saldo SET Cant_Uni=Cant_Uni+(2480*4), Cant_Peso_Kilo=Cant_Peso_KiloP+24800, Cost_Prom='1.00',Val_Inv='1.00' WHERE Id_Producto='00277';"); //Error de la prueba.
        $conn->commit();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $conn->rollback();
        $conn->beginTransaction();
        $conn->exec("set names utf8");
        $conn->exec("ALTER TABLE Tbl_Entradas AUTO_INCREMENT=1;");
        $conn->exec("ALTER TABLE Tbl_Lote AUTO_INCREMENT=1;");
        $conn->exec("ALTER TABLE Tbl_Saldo AUTO_INCREMENT=1;");
        $conn->commit();
    }
}
```

Para la prueba he insertado un error de sintaxis cambiando 'Cant_Peso_Kilo' por 'Cant_Peso_Kilo' en el ultimo query antes del commit

**Primero:** se supone que no deberia insertar/actualizar datos pero si lo esta haciendo, se insertan los dos primeros querys.

**Segundo:** no entiendo o no se por que al ejecutar algun rollback los primary Key quedan como si se ubiera insertado datos... y me toca en el catch ejecutar un rollback manual de los mismo autoincrementadores.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que MySQL tiene limitaciones en las transacciones, [según el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.begintransaction.php): *Algunas bases de datos, incluida MySQL, ejecután automáticamente un COMMIT implícito cuando una sentencia de definición de lenguaje de base de datos (DDL), tal como DROP TABLE o CREATE TABLE, se ejecutan en una transacción. El COMMIT implícito prevendrá de la reversión de cualquier otro cambio dentro del límite de la transacción.* Por otra parte, las tablas con engine `MYISAM` no admiten transacciones.

Comment: como marco que esta resuleto??? solo fue necesario pasar las tablas a innoDB...

Comment: Ahora agrego el comentario como respuesta para que puedas marcarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En los `CREATE TABLE` se ve que estás dando a las tablas el `ENGINE=MyISAM`.

Pero las tablas `MYISAM` no soportan transacciones, como se puede apreciar en [la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-storage-engine.html).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por tanto, para trabajar con transacciones, tienes que pasar las tablas al engine `INNODB`.

De todos modos, debes tener en cuenta que MySQL tiene algunas limitaciones con las transacciones, según [esta nota del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.begintransaction.php):

> Algunas bases de datos, incluida MySQL, ejecután automáticamente un
>   COMMIT implícito cuando una sentencia de definición de lenguaje de
>   base de datos (DDL), tal como DROP TABLE o CREATE TABLE, se ejecutan
>   en una transacción. El COMMIT implícito prevendrá de la reversión de
>   cualquier otro cambio dentro del límite de la transacción