# Rollback no funciona al momento que hay una excepción

Tags: php, pdo, insert, transacciones

muchas gracias por pasar y poder ayudarme, de verdad muchas gracias.
Tengo varias tablas que se alimenta con un formulario el problema es que al momento de que inician las inserciones a cada tabla si falla una solo se insertan los datos que estaban bien y en las tablas que están después del problema ya no, está configurada la opción de iniciar la transacción y el rollback pero no funcionan mi código es el siguiente:

```php
try
            {
                $this->conexion->beginTransaction();  
                
                $InsertDatosPapa = $this->conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO gesco_datosPapa VALUES(:Id, :LlenarPapa, :NombresPapa, :ApellidosPapa, :LugarNacPapa, :FechaNacPapa, :ReligionPapa, :NacionalidadPapa, :DPIPapa, :ExtendidoenPapa, :ProfecionOficioPapa, :DireccionPapa, :ZonaPapa, :ColoniaBarrioPapa, :DepartamentoPapa, :MunicipioPapa, :TelPapa, :CelPapa, :EmailPapa, :ParroquiaPapa, :GradoPapa, :TrabajoPapa, :TrabajoDireccionPapa, :TelefonoTrabajoPapa, :PuestoPapa)");
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":Id", $IdAlumno);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":LlenarPapa", $LlenarPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":NombresPapa", $NombresPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":ApellidosPapa", $ApellidosPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":LugarNacPapa", $LugarNacPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":FechaNacPapa", $FechaNacPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":ReligionPapa", $ReligionPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":NacionalidadPapa", $NacionalidadPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":DPIPapa", $DPIPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":ExtendidoenPapa", $ExtendidoenPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":ProfecionOficioPapa", $ProfecionOficioPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":DireccionPapa", $DireccionPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":ZonaPapa", $ZonaPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":ColoniaBarrioPapa", $ColoniaBarrioPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":DepartamentoPapa", $DepartamentoPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":MunicipioPapa", $MunicipioPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":TelPapa", $TelPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":CelPapa", $CelPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":EmailPapa", $EmailPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":ParroquiaPapa", $ParroquiaPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":GradoPapa", $GradoPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":TrabajoPapa", $TrabajoPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":TrabajoDireccionPapa", $TrabajoDireccionPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":TelefonoTrabajoPapa", $TelefonoTrabajoPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->bindparam(":PuestoPapa", $PuestoPapa);
                $InsertDatosPapa->execute();
                
                
                $InsertDatosMama = $this->conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO gesco_datosMama VALUES(:Id, :LlenarMama, :NombresMama, :ApellidosMama, :LugarNacMama, :FechaNacMama, :ReligionMama, :NacionalidadMama, :DPIMama, :ExtendidoenMama, :ProfecionOficioMama, :DireccionMama, :ZonaMama, :ColoniaBarrioMama, :DepartamentoMama, :MunicipioMama, :TelMama, :CelMama, :EmailMama, :ParroquiaMama, :GradoMama, :TrabajoMama, :TrabajoDireccionMama, :TelefonoTrabajoMama, :PuestoMama)");
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":Id", $IdAlumno);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":LlenarMama", $LlenarMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":NombresMama", $NombresMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":ApellidosMama", $ApellidosMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":LugarNacMama", $LugarNacMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":FechaNacMama", $FechaNacMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":ReligionMama", $ReligionMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":NacionalidadMama", $NacionalidadMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":DPIMama", $DPIMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":ExtendidoenMama", $ExtendidoenMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":ProfecionOficioMama", $ProfecionOficioMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":DireccionMama", $DireccionMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":ZonaMama", $ZonaMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":ColoniaBarrioMama", $ColoniaBarrioMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":DepartamentoMama", $DepartamentoMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":MunicipioMama", $MunicipioMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":TelMama", $TelMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":CelMama", $CelMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":EmailMama", $EmailMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":ParroquiaMama", $ParroquiaMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":GradoMama", $GradoMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":TrabajoMama", $TrabajoMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":TrabajoDireccionMama", $TrabajoDireccionMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":TelefonoTrabajoMama", $TelefonoTrabajoMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->bindparam(":PuestoMama", $PuestoMama);
                $InsertDatosMama->execute();
                
                
                $IdServicio = "SER-".uniqid();
                $InsertarSeguro = $this->conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO gesco_servicioMedico VALUES(:IdServicio, :NotificarNombre1, :NotificarTelefono1, :NotificarDPI1, :NotificarParentesco1, :NotificarNombre2, :NotificarTelefono2, :NotificarDPI2, :NotificarParentesco2, :IdAlumno, :AsistenciaMedica, :NombreServicio, :TelServicio, :NombreMedico, :TelClinica, :TelEmergencia, :Medicamento, :MedicamentoDes, :Alergia, :AlergiaDes, :Enfermedad, :EnfermedadDes, :TomaMedi, :TomaMediDes, :Quirurgica, :QuirurgicaDes, :Sangre, :IdCiclo, :Peso, :Altura)");
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":IdServicio", $IdServicio);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":NotificarNombre1", $NotificarNombre1);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":NotificarTelefono1", $NotificarTelefono1);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":NotificarDPI1", $NotificarDPI1);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":NotificarParentesco1", $NotificarParentesco1);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":NotificarNombre2", $NotificarNombre2);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":NotificarTelefono2", $NotificarTelefono2);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":NotificarDPI2", $NotificarDPI2);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":NotificarParentesco2", $NotificarParentesco2);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":IdAlumno", $IdAlumno);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":AsistenciaMedica", $AsistenciaMedica);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":NombreServicio", $NomServicio);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":TelServicio", $TelServicio);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":NombreMedico", $NombreMedico);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":TelClinica", $TelClinica);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":TelEmergencia", $TelEmergencia);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":Medicamento", $Medicamento);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":MedicamentoDes", $MedicamentoDes);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":Alergia", $Alergia);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":AlergiaDes", $AlergiaDes);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":Enfermedad", $Enfermedad);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":EnfermedadDes", $EnfermedadDes);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":TomaMedi", $TomaMedi);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":TomaMediDes", $TomaMediDes);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":Quirurgica", $Quirurgica);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":QuirurgicaDes", $QuirurgicaDes);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":Sangre", $Sangre);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":IdCiclo", $IdCiclo);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":Peso", $Peso);
                $InsertarSeguro->bindparam(":Altura", $Altura);
                $InsertarSeguro->execute();
                
                
                $InsertDireccionAlumno = $this->conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO gesco_alumnosDireccion VALUES(:Id, :Direccion, :Zona, :ColoniaBarrio, :Departamento, :Municipio)");
                $InsertDireccionAlumno->bindparam(":Id", $IdAlumno);
                $InsertDireccionAlumno->bindparam(":Direccion", $Direccion);
                $InsertDireccionAlumno->bindparam(":Zona", $Zona);
                $InsertDireccionAlumno->bindparam(":ColoniaBarrio", $ColoniaBarrio);
                $InsertDireccionAlumno->bindparam(":Departamento", $Departamento);
                $InsertDireccionAlumno->bindparam(":Municipio", $Municipio);
                $InsertDireccionAlumno->execute();
                
                $this->conexion->commit();
                return 1;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                $this->conexion->rollBack();
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
```

Dentro del Try de hecho hay más inserciones a otras tablas, pero si hay un error en alguna de ellas solo se inserta la información en las tablas donde no hubo error y las tablas que estén despues del error se quedan vacías.

Comment: Hola Manuel, para que las transacciones funcionen tienen que cumplirse algunas condiciones que he enumerado en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/135444/29967). Revisa cada una de ellas y dinos si se cumplen. [En este caso por ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/316807/29967), las transacciones no funcionaban porque el engine en que estaban las tablas era `MyISAM`, el cual no soporta transacciones.